# Varchar date to datetime sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `varchar` date format of 01012018, I need to convert this to a date in a SQL Server view:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CONVERT(DATE, [Date], 103), 103)
```

I have tried the above with no joy.

Please help

Comment: `DATE` doesn't have a format, what you have is a formatted string.

Comment: Negative marking has become an epidemic here, i can't see anything wrong with this question. This will discourage OP to ask further more.

Comment: The SQL you have would take a `varchar` representing a date with the format style `103` to a date, and then convert that `date` to a `varchar` with the date format style `103`. the outer expression completely reverses the inner expression.

Comment: The lack of explanation of "why" it didn't work, sample data, and expected results, and a lack of question (this is a Q&A website) are all reasons why this could be seen as a "bad" question @Ven (and I haven't downvoted).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server can be a bit cumbersome when parsing dates that are not one of the "built-in" ones.  You can use `parse()`/`try_parse()`, but that is a relatively new function.

In your case, it is pretty simple to construct the date value directly:

```
select convert(date, concat(right(ddmmyyyy, 4), substring(ddmmyyyy, 3, 2), left(ddmmyyyy, 2)))
from (values ('01012018')) v(ddmmyyyy)
```

Comment: And after you use the above solution, store it into a new column, and then maybe remove the string date column, which won't be very usable anyway +1.

Comment: `parse_date()` in SQL Server? I think you mean **[`PARSE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** / **[`TRY_PARSE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**

Answer (score 2):

There is no style `ddMMyyyy` in the `CONVERT` [Date and Time Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles), but there is a `dd/MM/yyyy`, so you could inject these characters in and convert:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date, STUFF(STUFF(v.ddmmyyyy, 5, 0, '/'), 3, 0, '/'), 103)
FROM (VALUES ('01012018')) v (ddmmyyyy);
```

I've also used `TRY_CONVERT` incase you have some other "bad" values (perhaps `'01312019'`). These will return `NULL` when the `varchar` represents an invalid date.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CONVERT()` as

```
DECLARE @Var VARCHAR(10) = '01012018'

SELECT CONVERT(DATE,
               CONCAT( RIGHT(@Var, 4),
                       SUBSTRING(@Var, 3, 2),
                       LEFT(@Var, 2)
                     )
              )
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b4dcd196f6d3996d2a45b43d8e882c5e)**

Finally, I would recommend `ALTER`ing your table (which is the right solution) and change the data type of your column to `DATE` data type.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  MyCol VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO T(MyCol) VALUES
('01012018'),
('01022018'),
('01032018'),
('WrongData');

SELECT MyCol
FROM T;

UPDATE T
SET MyCol = TRY_CONVERT(DATE,
                        CONCAT( RIGHT(MyCol, 4),
                                SUBSTRING(MyCol, 3, 2),
                                LEFT(MyCol, 2)
                              )
                        );
ALTER TABLE T
ALTER COLUMN MyCol DATE;

SELECT MyCol
FROM T;
```

**[Second Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1a3a1c4f7bcbe206fa410f58c8395710)**